# Using non-continuous verbs in continuous form

Tags: usage, continuous

I was learning non-continous verbs once again when I came across a site (I won't post a link to it, it's in russian). And it says that sometimes when we want to emphasize the action, we can use non-continous verb in continous form. And there's an example:

> I am hating him!

As the site says, expression above means that someone who said that hates "him" a lot.

I started searching for more info on this topic but found nothing. So my question is: *is that right that non-continuous verbs can be used in continous form and if so, how natural it sounds? How often do you say something like this?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Non-continuous verbs; verbs that cannot be used in continuous forms are usually verbs that you cannot see somebody doing

I wouldn't say that a lot.

I would say:

> I continue to hate him

Comment: So, if I understood you correctly, the conclusion is: they (verbs) can, but it's a rare case and might sounds unnatural. Right?

Comment: @Ruberoid yes that is correct